# Minimization of simple cyclic automata

Tags: finite-automata, reference-request, strings

Version 1 of the question: I am looking for any correct $O(n)$ algorithm in the literature which will solve the DFA minimization problem referred to in the quote below from [Almeida & Zeitoun 2008]. Whether the algorithm works on strings or automata doesn't matter.

Version 2 of the question: What is the classical algorithm being referred to in the quote below? The closest I've been able to get from reference [9] in the quote is algorithm SCOPES on page 307, but that requires that $k$ be given as an argument.

> Recall that the primitive root of a word $w$ is the shortest word $r$ 
>   such that $w = r^k$ for some $k$. It is easy to see that minimizing a
>   cycle 
>   $s_0 \xrightarrow{a_0} s_1 \xrightarrow{a_2} \ldots \xrightarrow{a_k} s_0$ 
>   amounts to finding a primitive root of its associated circular word: 
>   this primitive root is itself a circular word, and the cycle 
>   associated to it is the minimal automaton of the original cycle. 
>   It is classical 
>   that this computation can be performed in linear time 
>   (see *e.g.* [9] for instance).

[Almeida & Zeitoun 2008] J. Almeida and M. Zeitoun. [Description and analysis of a bottom-up DFA minimization algorithm](http://www.labri.fr/perso/zeitoun/research/pdf/Almeida-Zeitoun-IPL2008.pdf). Inform. Process. Lett., 107(2):52–59, 2008.

[9] M. Crochemore and W. Rytter. [*Text Algorithms*](http://monge.univ-mlv.fr/~mac/REC/text-algorithms.pdf). Oxford University Press, 1994.

Comment: I think you can do this if you first create a suffix tree.  I'll let you check the details.